# Cannot reach my external domains when connected to WireGuard VPN?

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, wireguard, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an Unraid server setup with services like WireGuard VPN, Home Assistant, Nginx Proxy Manager.
The setup is as follows:
WireGuard is running as "Remote tunneled access" with DNS server (192.168.1.1) which is my router.
Home Assistant is running as a Docker on the same server.
Nginx Proxy Manager is running as a Docker (Host) on the same server, here I have Nginx Reverse Proxy for Home Assistant (home.example.com).

I can without any issues reach Home Assistant when I am in my local network and when I use an external network. It is reachable from anywhere, as I want it to be.

But as soon as I connect to my WireGuard VPN tunnel it is no longer possible to reach the domain (home.example.com). It just times out.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: By default wireguard route all traffic to tunnel including your dns queries. Need to change routing. Until try reach by ip

Comment: @gapsf, reaching by IP works without any issues. But even though DNS queries are tunneled, it should work right? I am able to connect to the domain when I am at home connected to the network, so it should be the same thing when tunneled?

Comment: It depends on what dns server ip you use. Is it reachible via tunnel?

Comment: Yes, I can reach my DNS server (router) via 192.168.1.1 which is the same as it is configured in WireGuard.